# Add a parameter to a shared library in WebSphere

Tags: java, websphere, shared-libraries

I developped a shared library used by 2 web applications deployed in WebSphere 7.
This library is defined a the 'server' level. It main purpose is to read a file on the file system.
I set the path to the file in the Java code but I want to put it in WebSphere. 
Even if the path should not change before a long time, it would be much more cleaner.

Is it possible ? If no, what would be the best alternative ?

Thanks !

Comment: Do you mean a WebSphere shared library? If no, what do mean by "shared library"? If yes, what do you mean by "path to the file in the Java core", since the path to the file should be stored in WebSphere configuration?

Comment: Yes, it a WebSphere shared library. And yes, i would to store a parameter (a path to an external file) in the WebSphere configuration instead of the Java code. But i wonder where to add this (in WebSphere or in the JVM properties).

Comment: I still don't know what it means to store a WebSphere shared library path in Java code, but I've added an answer involving WebSphere variables that hopefully helps.

Comment: @bkail My understanding is that he has for example `new File("fixedPathInTheCode")` but would like to have `new File(VariableTakenFromWebSphereConfig)`. Solution proposed by Sergey will probably work.

Comment: @Gas You understand well ! Sorry for bad explaining :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can use JVM properties to store file path.

For example

`System.getProperty("myfile", "c:/file.txt");`

Add JVM property in WebSphere using web administrative console (ibm/console).

Open menu (for WAS7.0) `Websphere Application servers > server1 > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine > Custom properties` and click the `New` button.

Then enter the property name and value. Ckick `Apply` and `Save` button.

Restart  WebSphere Application Server. You will see property from application.

Comment: Welcome to SO.Little more explanation might hep outfellow programmers to understand how it works

Answer (score 0):

You should define a [WebSphere variable](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tcws_variable.html) (see the Procedure at the bottom) such as MY_LIBRARY_DIR, and then use it in the library classpath like ${MY_LIBRARY_DIR}/mylib.jar. You generally want to define the library at the same scope as the library, but if the library directory is in a different place on each node, you can also define the library at a cell scope and define the variable in each node.